# How to catch up an intensive, fast course?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

This semester, one of the graduate courses I take is *Real Analysis*-II and we follow Folland's Real Analysis. I have some other courses and a TAship too. I am more "*algebraist than analyst*". The professor is so quick, does a lot and assigns homework problems which mostly consists of iff questions. Every week I spend 2 or 3 days for this homework, I think, check my notes, and think again for hours. However, I am busy with all other works for the rest of the week. I usually forget some of the things that I did previous week before starting my new homework each week. I feel like I am not learning much and that bothers me a lot. So, my question is, how can I catch up the course and feel like "I am learning much"?

Comment: what you want to learn? why you feel you are not learning? I think that they are the key questions. Probably too much exercises and proofs are hiding the important points in the course, a typical case of "the trees dont let you see the forest", maybe?

Comment: For example, I have seen many types of compactness -the trees- ; the usual one, locally c., sigma c., sequentially c., para compact, countably compact. I proved theorems about these few weeks ago but I do not think that I am able to prove all of them again now. Also, I just "mechanically" proved them, I do not know how can I use them to see the "forest".